# How do I manage Google Chrome updates with the update manager?

Tags: update-manager, google-chrome

New Ubuntu user question. I have installed Google Chrome with software center and used terminal to get it to show up. 
Today Update Mgr ran and it said an update for chrome was ready so I accepted it and it downloaded. 
My question is do I have to do something else, like with terminal, to get it to update, or does the update mgr take care of everything?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need to do anything else. Just let Update Manager install the update, and that's it.

If you had Chrome running already, you might want to close Chrome and start it again: the running instance will be the previous version (maybe with some of the updated assets), which can sometimes cause problems. That isn't required, though. Update Manager will tell you if you need to restart your computer, and otherwise it should just work.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm learning. Love being out from under the Windows umbrella.

Answer (score -1):

if you install any .deb or install software via any software/package manager. its automatically add repository to sources. you can update with update manager or terminal with `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

how this help you

Comment: oh,so you can search for an upgrade on terminal before it shows up on update mgr? using the command you mentioned? thanks